# how to upload html file into cloude using predix

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints

What is the procedure to upload a html file into cloud.i tried with predix mailed link.but it is given error 403 .can anybody uploaded html files into cloud used predix platform link .please do need full.

Answer (score 0):

The hello world is an html file.  Please try this.
https://www.predix.io/resources/tutorials/journey.html#1719

You can serve up files within your microservice that you push up to the cloud.  See the rest endpoint /static in the Spring Boot doc.  Try out the microservice-template project for some ideas
https://www.predix.io/resources/tutorials/tutorial-details.html?tutorial_id=1523&tag=1719&journey=Hello%20World&resources=1475,1569,1523

Answer (score 0):

I have my collection of Predix.io apps in different languages including static HTML, angular, java even Scala etc.

Please look at

https://github.com/SVyatkin/CF-Hello-World-examples

According your question about HTML it is in the collection as well as just use

https://github.com/SVyatkin/CF-Hello-World-examples/tree/master/hello-html

```
$ git clone https://github.com/SVyatkin/CF-Hello-World-examples.git
$ cd CF-Hello-World-examples/hello-html
$ cf push -m 128M -b predix_openresty_buildpack html-hello
$ curl https://html-hello.run.aws-usw02-pr.ice.predix.io returns "HTML Predix.io - Hello World Example"
```